# Css path is wierd and not working

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to automate click on "tweet" button which is a part of iframe element.

I tried using css path, xpath but they are not working.

css path is like
html.regular body.hcount div#widget div.btn-o a#b.btn span#l.label

i also tried xpath but it is not working.

Selenium ide provides "1" value for it, which is not worked by webdriver.

Please suggest some way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the iframe element

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
//do your stuff
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

If that is not the problem please provide futher information.

Comment: i have to automate tweet button.. its same on all sites. 
www.101websites.com

Comment: ? I don't get your info? the domain is for sale

Comment: Steps: visit http://101bestwebsites.com/ , there i have to automate the clicks on the tweet button on the page.

Comment: Your page is awful. It has multiple iframes. You need to switch to the correct one before Selenium will correctly see an element. I really doubt your going to be able to automate this in a reliable way.

Comment: Yeah as I said you need to switch to the iframe then you should be able to click the button (the span).

Comment: 'code'
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("l")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html.regular body.hcount div#widget div.btn-o a#b.btn span#l.label")).click();
 // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="l"]")).click();
 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
'code'

I tried using CSS path.. its not working & xpath is showing error.
If this is not correct then please provide the correct code.

Comment: why so complicated? `By.cssSelector("a[id='b']")` should do the trick if the id is unique

Comment: selenium is still unable to locate and click the tweet button. Please write the complete code.